# MVC 5 Can an EditorTemplate call another EditorTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to do something like the following:  [Asp.Net MVC3 Razor - child items list not posting back from editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914228/asp-net-mvc3-razor-child-items-list-not-posting-back-from-editor)

The difference is that my Parent-Child relationship is one-to-many and my child-subchild relationship is one-to-many (as opposed to one-to-one and one-to-many respectively in the above example).  Also I do not have a ViewModel at this point.

I have something set up where a view uses and EditorTemplate, which in turn uses another EditorTemplate. It works except that but on HttpPost changes to the subchild (I don't need to allow the child to be edited) are not propagated to the database.

My main questions are:

Can I have an EditorTemplate call another EditorTemplate?
Do I need to have a ViewModel?

I think in my controller I need to save the changes to the DB... but I'm not sure how to pass the subchild information to the controller.  I know these questions are kinda basic and general... It would help if I had an example of the HttpPost controller action method for something like this.

Comment: Little bit too complicated to explain here, essentially you set your html names with indices, eg `subname[0][1]` and post back to an array or list then the default model binder will handle it all for you.  Here's more (offsite) info http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ but there's plenty of questions on SO that cover similar scenarios.  For your specific questions, you need an overall viewmodel and a (view)model for each level.  Easier if you don't use EditorTemplate, but instead use an explicit view.

Comment: @freedomn-m -- When you say "explicit view"... I don't think it's just one view, correct?  It's a 3 tiered hierarchy -- so each parent needs to be able to generate its children underneath of it, and each child needs to be able to generate its subchildren underneath of it.  Can that be done with a single view?  Ah... maybe with nested ForEach statements?

Comment: my point was to use a view rather than try to wedge it into EditorTemplate (in theory there should be no difference, but explicitly using a view rather than an implied template may make it easier to understand/control what's going on)

Comment: Short answer is yes. You have not shown your code so its impossible to guess what errors you have made.